# SQL select rows where id is the same

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to select the following values with the same ID. I basically have a submit form which stores its values and I want to display each submit. 
This is how the Databse Table looks like:

```
| id |         name |        value |
------------------------------------
|   1 |     venue_1 |     New York |
|   1 |      time_1 |        12:00 |
|   1 |     costs_1 |          50€ |
|   2 |     venue_1 |       Berlin |
|   2 |      time_1 |        15:00 |
| ... |         ... |          ... |
```

I want to display the values like this:

```
|      Venue |      Time |    Cost |
------------------------------------
|   New York |     12:00 |     50€ |
|     Berlin |     15:00 |     ... |
|    A Venue |  The time |    cost |
```

My SQL queries in PHP look like this (Joomla):

```
$db->setQuery('SELECT value FROM subrecords WHERE name = "venue_1"');
$venue = $db->loadColumn();

$db->setQuery('SELECT value FROM subrecords WHERE name = "time_1"');
$time = $db->loadColumn();
```

But when I loop through them to display them it doesn't match up:

```
foreach ($venue as $key => $val) {
    $output .= "<tr>
    <td>".$venue[$key]."</td>
    <td>".$time[$key]."</td>
    </tr>";
}
print($output);
```

I dont see through the logic here because as of now I just select all the venue_1 and time_1 etc and load the columns so I get every value but they need to be linked to each other so I can display them in the right way.

Where is my mistake? How can I link them through the ID maybe?

If something is unclear tell me please I don't want to make it difficult for you to help me :)

Comment: why downvote? Can you tell me how to match the id?

Comment: Your question does not deserve a downvote.  I can only give you one up vote.

Answer (score 4):

Here you can get all in one Query. When you delete the WHERE line you get the hole table

```
SELECT 
  Coalesce ((CASE WHEN name = "venue_1" THEN value END),NULL) Vebue,
  Coalesce ((CASE WHEN name = "time_1" THEN value END),NULL) Time,
  Coalesce ((CASE WHEN name = "cost_1" THEN value END),0) Coast
  FROM subrecords
  WHERE id = 1
  GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: Somehow returns nothing to me do you have a  solution with more simple SQL? I am pretty new to it and want to understand it

Comment: Well, it seems I only needed to ORDER BY id when selecting each column...I feel pretty stupid right now but thanks for the help